# Tortoise SVN - how to change context menu?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to change Tortoise SVN's context menu so that some of the commands I use more frequently appear one level higher in the menu?

eg right click the folder in explorer and you see these options

```
SVN Update
SVN Commit
Tortoise SVN ... (submenu)
```

I would like to be able to move or copy some items from the sub menu to the same level as update commit, eg

```
SVN Update
SVN Commit
Repo-browser
Show Log
Tortoise SVN ... (submenu)
```

I'm getting tired of expanding that sub menu every single time for commands I use all the time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely!  Right click in Explorer to get the context menu, then go into the Subversion sub-menu, and click Settings.  You can also find Settings under TortoiseSVN in your Start Menu.  In the Settings window you will find what you want under General -> Context Menu.  The items that are checked in the "Cascaded context menu" list box are the ones that will be in the top-level context menu.  I've customized mine and it really does make working with it quicker for me.

Comment: slightly off-topic, but this is another really useful TortoiseSVN tip: http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/09/26/optimize-tortoise-svn-cache-tsvncache.exe-disk-io.aspx